# Is there a way to use Edit And Continue when debugging a Prism application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, prism, edit-and-continue

we are developing a Prism application and as all modules are loaded using Reflection thru the Bootstrapper we cannot use the "Edit & Continue" feature which certainly increases productivity.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could manage to get Edit and Continue working with Prism! A few days ago i tried Edit and Continue with an Prism-Module and failed. Today i tried it again and what makes the difference is that i first test Edit and Continue with the Main-Project. I debugged the shell-view model and made than some changes in the source and Edit and Continue works as expected. After that i go to a module and surprise Edit and Continue starts working in the prism-modules. Maybe you can reproduce this behavior and report if it works. If not, we can go on and compare our projects to find the difference.

Regards
Christoph